# Minimal/Oldest Mac OS that allows the green screen for the Zoom video app

Tags: mac

What is the minimum oldest version of the Mac OS that allows the successful green screen for the Zoom video app?

I am asking the case with the camera on, with the person showing physical presence, and with the background JPG image of his/her own choice.

- 10.10.5 Yosemite does not work for the green screen.
- 10.11 High Sierra, does it work for the green screen?
- 10.15 Catalina does work for the green screen.

Some related discussions with various conditions:
https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360043484511-System-requirements-for-Virtual-Background#h_1d44b8c6-0031-4c8a-9300-8c1a722ba057

Comment: Although this is about a version of an App for macOS, the question could easily be generalized.  But use of background images/video is more dependant on the computer's abilities.  My sister's iMac with comparable (or worse) specs than my macMini (from comparable years and on the same OS) is able to use background video.  My mini is not

Comment: thanks so do you know which version for "iMAC" can use the green screen. It seems that the 10.10.5 Yosemite does not work for the green screen... I do not know why...

Comment: What about the linked Minimum requirements page do you not understand? Precisely which Mac are you trying to get this to work on?

Comment: It is not consistent with what I experienced, I use OS 10.10.5 Yosemite which is higher than the requirement page says OS 10.9 - but the OS 10.10.5 Yosemite does not to work to have a green screen. So I wonder why...

Comment: well, that half-answered my first question...